# What is the effect of caster angle in automobiles? What will happen if we use neutral caster?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, dynamics, car, linkage

What is the effect of **caster angle** in automobiles and what will happen if we use **neutral caster**?

[image]

We study that **positive caster** makes vehicle more stable at high speeds. It increases lean while cornering that's why it requires power steering. It has return ability or self aligning torque.

For **negative caster**, minimal steering input effort is required. It gives no feedback to the driver and it will unstable and increase under braking conditions. Best examples include office chairs, shopping carts etc.

a) What will happen if we use neutral caster?
b) What is the principle of swivel caster wheels? (other than (T=F.d)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why caster angle causes wheels to self-center?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48807/why-caster-angle-causes-wheels-to-self-center)

Comment: @SolarMike no sir.

Comment: @IbrahimOmer If the linked question about caster angle didn't answer your question, then you should make it clear what is different in your question or why the answers to the other question don't apply. Please [edit] you question.

Comment: @hazzey we use positive caster in automobiles, why cant we use neutral caster? Also the explanation other than (T=F.d) It is not the same question.

Comment: Mikes link tells you why we use positive caster. Which you can read as "the reason not to use neutral or negative caster".

Comment: The shopping trolley castor isn't much help, and the original drawings are for suspensions where the steering axis passes through the wheelcentre. This is neither necessary nor common. The most important dimension is between the point where the steering axis hits the ground, and the vertical up to the wheel centre. This is called mechanical trail and governs the steering feel at the steering wheel.

Comment: You also get some returnability from the lifting action onto the edge of the contact patch I suspect.  But most of the centreing on the move is because the forces are behind the steering axis.